# How to convert string Coordinates longitude and latitude into double

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gis

I have this function

```
public string getCoordinates(double latitude, double longitude)
{
    int latSeconds = (int)Math.Round(latitude * 3600);
    int latDegrees = latSeconds / 3600;
    latSeconds = Math.Abs(latSeconds % 3600);
    int latMinutes = latSeconds / 60;
    latSeconds %= 60;

    int longSeconds = (int)Math.Round(longitude * 3600);
    int longDegrees = longSeconds / 3600;
    longSeconds = Math.Abs(longSeconds % 3600);
    int longMinutes = longSeconds / 60;
    longSeconds %= 60;

    string result = string.Format("{0}° {1}' {2}\" {3}, {4}° {5}' {6}\" {7}",
         Math.Abs(latDegrees),
         latMinutes,
         latSeconds,
         latDegrees >= 0 ? "N" : "S",
         Math.Abs(longDegrees),
         longMinutes,
         longSeconds,
         latDegrees >= 0 ? "E" : "W");

    return result;
}
```

it converts from double into string latitude and longitude I need the inversion, that I have this format of string latitude and longitude and I want to convert it to double.

Comment: So what is preventing you from parsing your string, getting degrees, minutes and seconds parts and perform "back-to-degrees" computation?

Comment: i dont know how if i do i wouldn't ask rather i dont know much about coordinates and GIS things

Comment: [http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#C.23](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#C.23) this might help

Comment: What exactly part of "algorithm sketch" written by me causes problem to you? Parsing of string? Computing degrees from minutes and seconds? And by the way - what language are you planning to use from both mentioned in tags - JavaScript or C#?

Comment: well i tell you my case i have a map with city name its a map of saudi arabia city all of them i need these city locations on double format and wikimap give it to me on string format like this  27° 20′ 57.3″ N, 35° 41′ 46.2″ E and i'm creating a News website my client request that i mark every city with number of news related to google map on javascript its functions needs the latitude and longitude on float format so i want convert that into float format numbers i found your function is helpful but i need its inversion :) so i will appreciate a help

Comment: This is an good site for all your coordinates needs, it gives you javascript formula's. http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Comment: i found this http://www.directionsmag.com/site/latlong-converter/